# Floor tiles in bathroom

Tags: bathroom, tiling

I was wondering can anyone help me. I have just installed my bathroom wall tiles and am now going to the floor tiles. When I dry fit my floor tiles there is a gap of about 25-30mm around the shower tray. Can I offset my floor tiles from my wall tiles, so that I can get a bigger cut beside my shower tray?

Comment: To get rid of slivers, if that's your intention, shift the layout by 1/2 the tile width. You'll get the sliver size plus half the tile width at the 25-30mm gap spot. You'll still get a half tile at the opposite wall.

Comment: If there's an aesthetic problem with wall grout lines versus floor grout lines, then that's an expensive fix. Be sure to get it right next time, at least. Maybe it's not too late to return the floor tile and swap in something that works aesthetically?

Comment: Pics will help us understand your issue.  Are you doing tile on the bath floor or shower floor?  The rule is that you do the floor first then the wall tile. You have done things backwards, but it can be possibly overcome by changing the layout.

Comment: The easy way is to do what @popham has suggested.  Another way is to put the floor tiles diagonally.  Yet another option is to get larger tiles.  And yet another option is to get a set of narrow tiles and make a border on the floor.